# How to import Objc Files into my Swift files within my custom cocoapods framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

Simple explanation. I have created my own pod with name `BSSelectableView`, but within I need to use two files written in Objective-C. What do I need to achieve?

I need to make it visible within my Swift files, and also for people who will install my pod.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your Target needs a Bridging Header.

This is an Objective-C-Header-File with the name `[TargetName]-Bridging-Header.h`

Within this file, you have to `#import` all Objective-C-Headers you want to use in your Swift-Files.

You don't have to import anything in your Swift files.

[More information about Swift and Objective-C mixed projects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Comment: Will it work with Pod? I mean in directory what I said in question?

Comment: Since every pod is basically an own target, it should work, too. But I have never done this before

Comment: Where should I create bridging header for my pod target?

Comment: In the folder where the `BSView.swift` etc. are. This should usually be the main folder of your source-files

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create a [TargetName]-Bridging-Header file in your project.
2. import all the header files in bridging header file

Now you can use all objective c file in swift.